# C - While Loop Condition has OR with Char: Not Terminating

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, char

When using the logical OR operator in a while loop for Char values, the program does not run correctly.

The code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    char choice = 'y';

    while( choice != 'n' || choice != 'N') {

        int num;
        printf("\nEnter any number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        int i = num - 1;

        while(i >= 1) {
            num *= i;
            i--;
        }

        printf("Factorial is: %d\n", num);
        printf("Do you want to continue? \n");
        printf("Enter n to quit or y to continue\n");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
    }
}
```

**Ouput:**

```
Enter any number: 3
Factorial is: 6
Do you want to continue? 
Enter n to quit or y to continue
n

Enter any number: 3
Factorial is: 6
Do you want to continue? 
Enter n to quit or y to continue
N

Enter any number:
```

If I change the while statement, for example, to:

```
while( choice != 'n' ) {
```

The program runs fine. It is the logical OR that is creating an error.

Why is this issue occurring? And how do I make the program run with the OR logical operator?

Comment: `while( choice != 'n' || choice != 'N')` <-- one of these options is always true, so the loop continues forever

Answer (score 1):

The logical OR operator `||` evaluates to true if *either* expression is true.

So if `choice` is `N` then `choice != 'n'` is true, and if `choice` is `n` then `choice != 'N'` is true.  If `choice` is neither of those, then both are true.  So the full condition will always be true.

You want to instead use the logical AND operator `&&`.  This evaluates to true only if *both* expressions are true.

```
while( choice != 'n' && choice != 'N') {
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put `n`, `choice != 'N'` is true and it continues.

If you put `N`, `choice != 'n'` is true and it continues.

There should be `&&` instead of `||`.